# Is there an easy way to allow Point to accept doubles or is there any alternative?

Tags: java

I am doing some computation in Java and it worked fine but I noticed my numbers were slightly off from my python implementation.  It took me like an entire day but I believe this is due to me having to cast my data to INT to use point.  I am very new so I could be wrong but I read in the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) that it seems to accept ints only (perhaps I misunderstood it). The reason I really liked point was because my data was in a similar format and I did not want duplicates.  Data format example: (1,0), (1,2),(10,2),etc..

I guess my two questions are:

1. Is there a way to get point to accept doubles? or is it going to be really difficult for a beginner to do?
2. If its not possible, are there any alternative data structures I can use to achieve the same thing(thought of hash map but I thought it would replace (1,0) with (1,1) which my program would consider unique)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Point` is mainly for GUI purposes where you have integer pixel values. Try [Point2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Point2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html)

Comment: Please don't link to old JavaDocs.

Comment: It seemed more useful than just complaining. ;)

Comment: @LouisWasserman fixing it is far more useful, but without some "pressure" people won't learn or even notice it ;)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use the `setLocation()` method in the Point API to pass double values to a Point object:</strike>

**EDIT**:

It was pointed out that the Point class setLocation() method rounds to an integer value, so probably not what you want. My mistake.

But the [Point2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) class has a constructor that accepts doubles, which probably is what you want.

Comment: `setLocation(double, double)` would round the values and thus would result in integer values being stored. Thus that would not be an option here.

Comment: Well, the JavaDoc on `Point` says it handles the coordinate in integer precision. Thus some form of rounding _has_ to be employed. Looking at the source, you find: `this.x = (int) Math.floor(x+0.5);` etc.

Comment: @Thomas I am not that familiar with the Point API. I knew that there was a `setLocation()` that took doubles as parameters, but I haven't really spent much time using Point objects. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

In the API documentation that you linked to, you can see this:

> Nested classes inherited from class java.awt.geom.Point2D
>
> `Point2D.Double`, `Point2D.Float`

You can for example use `Point2D.Double`:

```
Point2D.Double p = new Point2D.Double(1.0, 2.0);
```