# The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Point2D.Double

Tags: java

I'm not sure what's going on here but here's a section I'm having problems with (there's a few others but I think if I can figure out the logic here I can apply it elsewhere).

I recently had a problem where I was using point but couldn't get decimals so, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874487/is-there-an-easy-way-for-a-newbie-to-allow-point-to-accept-doubles-or-is-there-a), I switched to [point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) to allow for doubles.  Since switching I have been getting errors that I can't seem to understand how to fix because I don't see the cause (I know changing to point2D triggered it but I can't see the connection).

I have the following code:

```
Double x_data = (Double) data.get(k); 
for (int c = 0; c <= 100; c++) { //the c variable caps the percent
    double percent = roundTwoDecimals(c*.01);
    double value1 =(sum - percent * x_data);
```

data is a list of point2D(which I'm casting to to double and sum is a variable I send in to this method that is really an integer but I cast it as a double. In eclipse I get the dreaded red underline under 'percent * x_data'. I googled and saw this error is often caused by someone trying to multiply a string or something but I'm fairly certain these all doubles. I get the following error now:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Point2D.Double
    The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Point2D.Double
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete ArgumentList
    The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Point2D.Double
```

As far as I can tell everything involved in this process is either double or casted to double so I'm not sure why Point2D is involved in these operators.

Also I had a method that limited decimal places:

```
static double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
```

but Double.valueOf is not one of the options anymore so I got errors (Point2D errors) on that(to get around it, I just return d back right now without limiting the decimals).

I don't think there is a problem with point2D or anything but I must be structurally doing something wrong.

Comment: From what I see in the exception, you are trying to multiply a variable of type `double` with type `Point2D.Double` using the `*` operator. The Java VM is telling you it does not know how to do that. Maybe you have imported `Point2D.Double` which overrides the `Double` that is the object version of the native type `double`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the stack trace, x_data is of type `Point2D.Double`, not `java.lang.Double`.
Check your imports, remove `Point2D.Double` and add `java.lang.Double`.

Now you won't be able to cast a `Point2D` to a `Double`. You probably mean to use `yourDoublePoint2D.getX()` adn `yourDoublePoint2D.getY()` which return `double`s (no cast required).

As a side note, you can write something like this:

```
Double d1 = 1.5;
double d2 = 2.3;
double d3 = d1 * d2;
```

**EDIT**
You are likely importing `Point2D.Double` class with this:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D.*;
```

or

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double;
```

That creates a name collision with `java.lang.Double`. See below an example of code that would work as you expect:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D; //Note: only import Point2D, not Point2D.Double

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(1.5, 2.5);
        double x = point.getX(); //1.5
        double y = point.getY(); //2.5
        Double xx = point.getX(); //1.5
        Double yy = point.getY(); //2.5
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what your saying and it makes sense but I need to use both.  I need Point2D.Double and (in this case) java.lang.Double...I *think* when I imported point2D.Double, it converted all my other doubles into that one.  Is there a way to use a specific double for one set of variables and another for different set?

Comment: yes, specify it by it's full name like this `java.lang.Double` instead of `Double`. This also works for Point2D.Double btw

Comment: @len Thanks thats great to know.  I'l start testing, but is there a way to make one default over the other? My code is pretty large and instead of changing the many references I have to java.lang.Double, I would rather keep those intact and simply just specifically call Point2D.Double when I need it.

Comment: Yes, where you need the Point2D.Double replace Double with java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double (assuming that that is the class you are using)

Comment: @len I understand that but how do it get it to default to java.lang.Double when I added Point2D.Double, all my existing doubles started acting weird and I think its because point2D took over, is there a way to change the default Double so it goes back to java.lang.Double? Does the order of imports change this?

Comment: @learningJava There is no "default Double". If you need to use a `Double` (the number), you need to use `java.lang.Double`. If you want to use a `Double` (the `Point2D` that uses `double` coordinates) you need to use `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`. This is generally solved by adding an import at the top of your file. But if you need to use both in your code, you need to fully specify at least one of them.

Comment: The only way to do that is removing the import at the start. It should look like this `import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`. If you imported the whole thing, it will look like this `import java.awt.geom.Point2D.*`. Remove that and import specific classed from Point2D EXCEPT the Double obviously ;). java.lang.Double should now be back to normal

Comment: assylias and @len Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! I can't thank you enough..I spent the weekend exploring ways of solving my problem and was sooo confused that my numbers are slightly off, I thought I'd try using doubles but ran into problems and couldn't figure out why my entire program broke when doing that.  You two really help me understand and gave me another thing to look out for when troubleshooting.  Thanks so much! I just went from hating java to loving it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't import Point2D.Double, but refer to all instances of it by the full package name, an "unadorned" Double should be java.lang.Double.