# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double

Tags: java, eclipse

i want to create a calculator .my code run in "cmd" successfully .but it didn't run in eclipse.it shows error in line 79."Double result =d1+d2;" here. 
error show that:
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Double,   java.lang.Double
please help.

> part of a class

```
    try{
        String s1 = txtFirst.getText(); String s2 = txtSecond.getText();
        Double d1= Double.valueOf(s1); 
        Double d2= Double.valueOf(s2);
        Double result = d1+d2 ; 
        String s = String.valueOf(result);
        txtResult.setText(s);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "Input Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `java.lang.Double`? You may have to check your imports to see if another class `Double` is being imported. [Similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876005/the-operator-is-undefined-for-the-argument-types-double-point2d-double)

Comment: import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.lang.Double;

Comment: you are using Double class instead of double variable check my answer..

Comment: What are the values of `d1` and `d2` if you print them out before the additon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using old version of java which doesn't use AutoBoxing". Hence either upgarde java or use "double" instead of "Double" like this.

```
try{
    String s1 = txtFirst.getText(); String s2 = txtSecond.getText();
    double d1= Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2= Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1+d2 ; 
    String s = String.valueOf(result);
    txtResult.setText(s);
}catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "Input Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: there is no issue in using Double class.. This is not the problem.

Comment: You have heard of autoboxing?

Comment: i don't know much about autoboxing but i think problem with parsing or somthing else.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir Using an older version of Java that doesn't have autoboxing, maybe?

Comment: @AntonH ah yes! Java 5 below doesn't use Autoboxing. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Your answer is correct but edit your post to make it more meaningful by saying, "You may be using old version of java which doesn't use AutoBoxing". Hence either upgarde java or use "double".

Comment: @TahirHussainMir ok brother

Answer (score 0):

Which java version are you using ? because Autoboxing and Unboxing came  in Java 5.0
If you are using old java version then you can't typecast directly.In that case you need to use below code

```
try{
    String s1 = txtFirst.getText(); String s2 = txtSecond.getText();
    double d1= Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2= Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1+d2 ; 
    String s = String.valueOf(result);
    txtResult.setText(s);
}catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "Input Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```